# Unexpected behavior of ContinuedFractionK with function defined by SetDelayed

Tags: function-construction, continued-fractions

I cannot explain the following results:
First, I define a function `f`.
Then `ContinuedFractionK` imvolving `f` results in `0`.
Afterwards, I delete `f`.
Now `ContinuedFractionK` gives the desired symbolic result.
When I define `f`  and let `f` act on the symbolic answer, the result is correct.

```
f[0] = 1; f[1] = 1; f[n_] := n

ContinuedFractionK[f[k], f[k + 1], {k, 0, 3}]
```

> 0

```
Clear[f]

ContinuedFractionK[f[k], f[k + 1], {k, 0, 3}]
```

> f[0]/(f[1] + f[1]/(f[2] + f[2]/(f[3] + f[3]/f[4])))

```
f[0] = 1; f[1] = 1; f[n_] := n

f[0]/(f[1] + f[1]/(f[2] + f[2]/(f[3] + f[3]/f[4])))
```

> 38/53

Can anybody explain why this happens? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Your definition

```
f[n_] := n
```

is very general.  So general, in fact, that `f[k]` evaluates immediately to `k`.  Restrict the pattern so that it will only evaluate for numeric quantities:

```
f[0] = 1; f[1] = 1; f[n_?NumericQ] := n

ContinuedFractionK[f[k], f[k + 1], {k, 0, 3}]
(* 38/53 *)
```